# Match url path and ip address from string

Tags: regex, ruby

How to match two parts of the string?

Example string:

```
/some/page_path 255.122.212.211
```

The first part I want to match is a valid path, a simple check if starts with / and no white spaces. (and maybe special signs?)

The second part is just checking the IP address if has a pattern of (0-9) numbers with dots.

Example of bad string:

```
/some/page _path 2525.122.212 yada yada
```

Regex I have for IP:

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}
```

Comment: If the left part is really an URL, it can't have embedded space. Therefore you can, IMO, do without pattern matching, but simply split on the space which separates the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```rb
/\A(?:\/[^\/\s]+)+\s+(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\z/
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/FoUkEJcsxg2sEU). *Details*:

- `\A` - start of string
- `(?:\/[^\/\s]+)+` -  one or more occurrences of `/` and then one or more chars other than `/` and whitespace
- `\s+` - one or more whitespace chars
- `(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}` - three occurrences of one to three digits followed with a `.` char, and then one to three digits
- `\z` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed that the last part of the string must be a valid IPv4 address.

```
require "ipaddress"
```

```
def str_parts(str)
  path, ip_str = str.split(/ +/,2)
  raise "'#{path}' is an invalid path" unless path_valid?(path)
  raise "'#{ip_str}' is an invalid ip address" unless ip_valid?(ip_str)
  [path, ip_str]
end
```

```
def path_valid?(path) 
  path.match?(/\A(?:\/[^\/\s]+)+\z/)
end
```

```
def ip_valid?(ip_str) 
  IPAddress.valid?(ip_str)
end
```

The regular expression I have used in `path_valid?` is taken from the first part of the expression given by @Wiktor. A more definitive operating system-specific check could of course be used. See the [doc](https://github.com/ipaddress-gem/ipaddress) for the *ipaddress* gem. Note that I have used [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-split)'s optional second argument.

```
str_parts("/some/page_path 255.122.212.211")
  #=> ["/some/page_path", "255.122.212.211"]
str_parts("/some/page _path 2525.122.212 yada Yoda")
  #=> RuntimeError ('_path 2525.122.212 yada Yoda' is an invalid ip address) 
str_parts("/some/page_path 255.122.256.211")
  #=> RuntimeError ('255.122.256.211' is an invalid ip address)
str_parts("/some//page_path 255.122.212.211")
  #=> RuntimeError ('/some//page_path' is an invalid path)
```

---

An alternative to using the *ipaddress* gem would be to write:

```
def ip_valid?(ip_str) 
  (IPAddr.new(ip_str) rescue nil)&.ipv4?
end
```

See [IPAddr::new](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-c-new) and [IPAddr#ipv4?](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-i-ipv4-3F). `&` is Ruby's [Safe Navigation Operator](https://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/).